# How to make immutable 2D Array in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following class:

```
class Matrix(val matrix: Array[Array[Int]]) {
// some other methods
override def toString: String = {
    return matrix.map(_.mkString(" ")).mkString("\n")
  }   
}
```

I have declared class variable as `val` to prevent further modification in `matrix`.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val > = Array
    val x: Array[Array[Int]] = >(
      >(1, 2, 3),
      >(4, 5, 6),
      >(7, 8, 9))

    val m1 = new Matrix(x)
    println("m1 -->\n" + m1)
    x(1)(1) = 101 // Need to prevent this type of modification.
    println("m1 -->\n" + m1)
  }
}
```

After doing `x(1)(1) = 101` the output of the program is

```
m1 -->
1 2 3
4 101 6
7 8 9
```

But I want to prevent this modification and get the original matrix as

```
m1 -->
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: `val` only makes the variable cannot be reassigned by other collection but you still can reassign the field in the collection

Comment: Could you tell me how to prevent this modification?

Comment: Use an immutable data type instead of a mutable one. `Array` is mutable (even if the reference to it is not). You can simply use `IndexedSeq` which serves as a generic trait for sequences with constant random access. The official documentation has a very interesting chapter on collections and their characteristics: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between a mutable/immutable variable (e.g. `var x` and `val x`) and a mutable/immutable collection. Declaring one (the variable) doesn't effect the other (the collection).

The Scala `Array` is inherited from Java and, as such, is mutable. There are many fine immutable collections. `Array` isn't one of them.

Comment: The fact that this is a matrix leads me to believe that there is likely to be a lot of random access. As such, the best option from the built-in immutable collections would be Vector. However, looking at the code for Vector it doesn't appear that it is specialized as of Scala 2.12.2. That means that all the Ints will be wrapped values, not the 4-byte primitives. I would suggest writing a bit more code so you create an immutable wrapper around Array[Array[Int]] with an appropriate apply method. If you would like a full answer on this approach, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Array, maybe you could use List instead, and it is immutable :

```
scala> val num:List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
num: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> num(1) = 3
<console>:13: error: value update is not a member of List[Int]
   num(1) = 3
   ^
```

Comment: I am using ListBuffer. Could you tell me how can I cast `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]]` to `List[List[Int]]`?

Comment: `buff.map(_.toList).toList`

Comment: You really don't want Lists for matrices. They are likely going to be random access so this will have a lot of overhead.